# TextView drawable rotation with MotionLayout

Tags: android, android-motionlayout

I'd like to rotate the drawable of `TextView` depending on the progress of animation. The textView is part of MotionLayout, that's being animated. Ideally I'd like to avoid using kotlin code to do that, just XML

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/thumb"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_chevron_left_black_24dp"
    android:drawablePadding="0dp"
    android:drawableTint="@color/white"/>
```

So I'd like to rotate the drawable, not the entire `TextView`. Does any one know whether this is possible? I only see examples of rotatin the entire widget.

Answer (score 0):

The `drawableStart` you specified within your `TextView` can not be animated like the TextView itself as the drawable is not a direct child of the MotionLayout. That is the case of the XML way. But you can always perform any kind of animation using Java/Kotlin by simply  applying animations on `MotionLayout.TransitionListener` callbacks.